# Multidimensional array to single array in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter, multidimensional-array

I am working in PHP so I have an array like this, from this array I want filter take `user_id` to another array like I given below.

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [user_id] => 66
            [distance] => 0
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [user_id] => 68
            [distance] => 0
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [user_id] => 81
            [distance] => 0
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [user_id] => 65
            [distance] => 0.00010218008081861118
        )

)
```

I want an array like this,

```
$user_id=array(66,68,81,65);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Where `$array` is the multidimensional array you provided above:

```
$data = array();
foreach ($array as $item) {
    $data[] = $item['user_id'];
}
print_r($data);
```

Answer (score 6):

Use [array_column()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php)

> Returns an array of values representing a single column from the input array.

```
<?php

$user_array = array(
                  0 => array('user_id' => 1, 'name' => 'Bob'),
                  1 => array('user_id' => 2, 'name' => 'John'),
                  2 => array('user_id' => 3, 'name' => 'Mary')
              );

$users = array_column($user_array, 'user_id');

print_r($users);
```

Output :

```
Array
(
   [0] => 1
   [1] => 2
   [2] => 3
)
```

Comment: Learn something new everyday! Didn't even know this function existed.

Comment: That's the beauty of programming, always discovering new things. ^_^